# Install TLS 1.2 Certificate on iOS App

Tags: ios, tls1.2, app-transport-security

How do I install a certified TLS certificate on an iOS app?

I assume there also needs to be the ability to send a new certificate over the network to the app in the future, if need be, and how exactly would that work?

I assume once it's installed that Apple will handle the entire handshake process of the device side?

Had some trouble finding explicit answers to these questions online.

Comment: What precisely do you mean by "a certified TLS certificate"?

Comment: @duskwuff once my server is completed I'm going to get a certificate from a CA, is what I meant. Asking once I get that certificate, how do I get it on the iOS app and start using it? I've read that the certificate is shared during the first handshake... but how is it shared, do I have to worry about it on the iOS side or just simply send it from my server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that what you are describing is a signed SSL certificate for your domain name, the only thing you will need to do is install it on your web server. When your application makes a request to your web server, the server will send the certificate to the client during the initial HTTPS handshake, and the client will verify it automatically.

Comment: Nitpick: install on the server the server cert **and the chain cert(s)** specified by the CA (usually one but occasionally two or three), and the handshake sends all of them. If you are missing the server cert, the server can't handshake at all and no client can connect. If you are missing a chain cert, some clients may connect but some fail in a pattern incomprehensible to anyone but an expert; this is undesirable.